# Rotate Models Incrementally

Tags: modifiers

I have 35 objects, and I need to rotate them such that they complete a 180° rotation. Thus, I need each one to rotate n*5.14°.

Is there a way to do this easily in Blender?

Comment: Are the objects all identical?

Comment: should they be aligned , as if showing different angles of the same object

Answer (score 3):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but if you're looking to form a bunch of objects into a 180° semicircle, you can use an **Array Modifier**:

[image: screenshot]

Just use an *Empty* as the offset object of the modifier, and keep the origin of the object in the same place as the empty. Then you can rotate the empty by `180/(35-1)` to get the right increments to fill up 180°.

[image]

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is now the preferred upload site because its uploads do not expire. See: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting